# How do you remove the colon from a time in the "HH:MM" format when the time is placed in the range from an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database of times formatted as "8:00 AM", "12:00 PM", etc.  I need to transfer those times to a different sheet in a different format.

Ex:
Sheet 1:

```
8:00 AM
9:00 AM
12:00 AM
2:00 Pm
2:43 PM
```

Sheet 2:

```
800
900
1200
200
243
```

I tried to just use the left and right functions, but it would read it as a decimal.

```
'For single digit hours
NewTime(i) = Left(NewTime(i),1) & Right(NewTime(i),2)
```

Comment: In Excel, time is a decimal number (Double). Today, July 17th 2023, is 45124. Each day is +1, each hour is +1/24 and each minute is +1/1440. So tomorrow at 8:30 PM would be 45125.854167. Normally, these numbers are displayed as a date and time by excel but "behind the curtain" all dates are numbers. This is why `Left` and `Right` won't work on a date value. You could do `Range.Text` instead of `Range.Value`, but the better solution is to just change the display with `Range.NumberFormat` as BigBen answered.

Answer (score 2):

You apply a new `.NumberFormat` to the range, e.g.

```
Sheet2.Range("A1:A5").NumberFormat = "hmm"
```